# Splitting field of a polynomial has a solvable group of automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

Prove that splitting field of a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{k}[x]$ ($f = 0$ solvable by radicals) has a solvable group of automorphisms $Aut_\mathbb{k}(\mathbb{F})$.

I have just started learning Galois theory, any advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What textbook are you using? Jacobson's Basic Algebra I, chapter 4, explains this in detail. I would guess that any textbook at similar level would also cover this. One way is to show first that adjoining the required roots of unity won't change the solvability of the Galois group, and then, assuming that the ground field has those root of unity, the links in a root tower extension all give cyclic composition factors to the Galois group.